# Nexus Repository Manager does not release storage after asset deletion

Tags: docker, docker-registry, nexus

I have a Nexus (version 3.30.0) for a docker registry:

Since a lot of TB data has accumulated here over time, I have built a script that analyses in a relatively complex way which images are no longer needed and then also deletes them via the API with `[DELETE] /v1/assets/{id}`.

The images are also deleted wonderfully, but the storage space remains the same. I have also run the Admin Task Compact Blob Store without success.
It has been several days since the images were deleted.

Do I have to do anything else to free up the storage? For example, delete unused blobs or something? Does anyone know anything about this?

Thanks already

Answer (score 0):

If Nexus Repository Manager is not releasing storage after asset deletion, it is possible that the deletion process is not properly removing all references to the asset from the repository's metadata. This can lead to the asset still being counted as part of the repository's storage, even though it is technically deleted.

To resolve this issue, you can try performing a repository rebuild, which will rebuild the repository's metadata and remove any references to deleted assets. To do this, follow these steps:

Log in to Nexus Repository Manager as an administrator.
Navigate to the repository in question.
Click on the "Tasks" tab.
Click on the "Create Task" button.
Select "Rebuild repository search" from the list of tasks.
Configure the task to run on the repository in question, and select any other appropriate settings for your use case.
Click on the "Create" button to create the task.
Wait for the task to complete.
After the task completes, the repository's metadata should be rebuilt, and any references to deleted assets should be removed. This should free up any storage space previously occupied by the deleted assets.

Note that rebuilding a repository's metadata can be a resource-intensive task, and may take some time to complete depending on the size of the repository. It is also recommended to perform a backup of the repository before performing any maintenance tasks.
[NOHSAD.COM](https://nohsad.com/)

Comment: This does not work for me. I have run the job Rebuild repository search and also rebuild repository browse. Unfortunately, nothing has changed in the storage requirements.